# EF Core reload all entities for an entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In EF Core you can "reload" an Entity from the data store to pickup any changes.

An example of why you might need to do that is if you need to resolve a DB concurrency exception on `SaveChanges`.

This does work ok for one record...

```
EntityEntry<T> entityEntry = GetEntity(123);
entityEntry.Reload();
```

The only problem is, the `Reload()` executes a SQL statement per `entityEntry`.

So, if you want to refresh a set of `entityEntry`, you get a SQL statement per entry.

Whereas, the normal `context.Set<T>().Load();` executes one SQL statement that retrieves all of the rows.

With a small number of `entityEntry`, the performance hit is negligable; but anytime I see a RBAR design approach, it raises a red flag for me.

Question: other than a RBAR loop

```
foreach (var e in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>)  
{
     e.Reload(); 
}
```

is there a way to re-execute the `context.Set<T>().Load();` to reload the entries as a set?

Note: I am using the

```
context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Detached
```

approach now; checking to see if there is something better that I have missed.

**UPDATE 1**

How I am testing

1. Read data from database
2. Add record to database
3. Delete record from database
4. Change record in database
5. "reload" data

the result I am looking to get is

- entity for changed record is updated
- entity for deleted record is removed
- "optionally" entity for new record is added
  the Add is optional because that is not the designed behaviour of "reload", which is to update existing entity.

Comment: `context.Set<T>().Where(x => entityItds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList()` also reloads entities if they are not modified. So just collect Ids and use in this query.

Comment: Nice approach; but doesnt actually update the Entity like Reload does. It seems like EF reads the data from the data store, then throws it away.

Comment: Better to read EF Core documentation about ChangeTracker. Mark modified entities as Unchanged and run query above.

Comment: that is the point. the Entities are already Unchanged, but have changed in Data Store. I want to refresh the Entities with the updated values in the Data Store. (eg do the Reload() but on all entities not just one).

Comment: Instead, setting them to `Detached` then executing the query above, does it do it?

Comment: Probably, but really defeats what I would like to do. The approach I am exploring now is "discard entire UI state and rebuild from scratch". with a small UI (eg android app) this is fast enough. with a large UI (say 5000+ records) doing a rebuild has a huge time hit.